# Can we use django filter with a variable?

Tags: python, django, variables, filter, hardcode

Here are my codes:

Models.py

```
class Members(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
      username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      email = models.EmailField()
      phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
```

Views.py (fails to return any value)

```
def employeeView(request):
    member = User.username
    members = Members.objects.filter(username= member)
    return render(request,'members/user_profile.html', {'members': members})
```

Views.py (returns properly)

```
def employeeView(request):
    members = Members.objects.filter(username= 'mahesh')
    return render(request,'members/user_profile.html', {'members': members})
```

I am trying to get the data out by filtering the Members.obejcts by passing the username of the logged-in user. It works when hardcoded, but not by passing a variable. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried debugging, to see what `User.username` actually is? Usually, the logged-in user is `request.user`, not `User. I would think that `User.username` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead, `member = request.user.username`